# Database normalization how to normalize approvals/status

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-normalization

I'm learning normalization and got some confusion. I'm working on a table.
Request table.

- requestid
- quantity
- requestedby
- requestdate
- approver1
- approver1_additionalinfo
- approval1_dateapproved
- approval1_status(denied/approved)
- approver2
- approver2_additionalinfo(regarding request)
- approval2_dateapproved
- approval2_status(denied/approved)

Per database normalization, fields that are not directly dependent should be separated so i put approval on the separate table.(correct me if i'm wrong)

Table name: Approval1

1. ApprovalID
2. RequestID
3. ApproverID
4. DateApproved
5. AdditionalInfo(type int)
6. Status(denied/approved)

Table name: Approval2

1. ApprovalID
2. RequestID
3. ApproverID
4. DateApproved
5. AdditionalInfo(type nvarchar)
6. Status(denied/approved)

Based on this design, information regarding request will be on 3 tables and will need more joins to query. It may impact performance.

What is the best approach for this?

Hope someone enlighten me on this. Thanks

Comment: It seems you should have a separate table for approvals with a foreign key back to the related request.

Comment: Okay lets say we will create approval table like

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Reference your text & show your work. So far this shows no understanding whatsoever of "normalization".

Comment: Thanks philipxy, okay. Lets say i'll separate approval on another table. With fields ApprovalId,requestid,additionalinfo,dateapproved,approverid,status. Is it good practice to put other fields to separate tables, lets say we we 4 levels of approvals. I, will be needing lot of joins to query the dat.

Comment: Please clarify via editing your post, not via comments. Although you haven't addressed all my last comment. You are still just asking us to rewrite your textbook & do your homework. PS Google 'stackexchange notifications' re how & when to use @ to notify another users about a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get rid of approver_1 etc. and move that off to a separate table.  This is normalisation 101.

2) Use SQL Server temporal tables to maintain a history of change if you need just a copy of values.  If you need a workflow type thing then you may need a new table but it's hard to tell without full requirements.

Comment: Thanks Lozt. Lets say i'll create table for approvals and put common fields like approvalid,requestid,approverid,approvaldate,status. How will i handle the other fields that are not common to the approval table. Should i create another sub table to store the additional info? My worry is that i will have to build query w/ lot of joins just to retrieve all requests information.

Comment: The other columns stay where they are or move to another table as appropriate. Don't concern yourself with the number of joins. That's what database are for. Get your data model straight first. You don't know what the performance will be until you're done, so don't guess. Chances are it will be fine.